# eval() doesn't execute external (src=...) scripts

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser

I'm using `eval()` to execute all `<script>` tags after total rewrite of a div (whose code is loaded via an `XMLHttpRequest`):

```
var arr = document.getElementById('idOfDIV').getElementsByTagName('script');
         for (var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++){
                try {
                 eval(arr[n].innerHTML);
                } catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
                }
        }
```

It works well for inline-scripts, but has no effect on scripts like:

```
<script src="/path/to/externalScript.js"></script>
```

How come? Can I "force" the browser to load and execute also the external scripts?

NOTE: As I noted, the question may seems "strange", regarding the fact that `eval()` executes a string as javascript. What I need to do, is the force the browser to load external scripts contained in "pasted" DOM, and execute them.

Comment: um you can't really do that since the script tags don't have the source in the HTML. you could add the script tags again but that could cause a lot of leaks.

Comment: Remember: eval() is evil

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to do -- `eval()` runs a string as executable JavaScript code, it doesn't do anything with HTML tags. If you were using jQuery, I'd suggest the [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) method.

Comment: @Logard: I know; but in this case is my only option.

Comment: @Blazemonger: You're right, I'm updating the question with a note

Comment: Incidentally, this is part of the reason why separation of concerns is a good idea -- HTML and JavaScript shouldn't be intertwined this much in the first place. I'd suggest taking all the scripts out of that `div` and combining them together somewhere else in a single function.

Comment: `eval` is meant to evaluate **JavaScript** code, **not HTML**.

Comment: @plalx: I know... As I already stated, I need to have the script retrieved and then executed via eval()

Comment: Use AJAX to retrieve the external file if there's an `src` attribute, and `eval()` whatever you get.

Comment: eval is evaluating Javascript in this code, as `arr` is a list of <script> node ..  also see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml

Answer (score 3):

This tag :

```
<script src="/path/to/externalScript.js"></script>
```

has empty innerHTML, so you cant eval the content

What you could do is to check if the script has an `src` attribute, and add a script tag in the head with this src :

```
function addHeadScript = function(src){
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = src;
    head.appendChild(script);
}

...


for (var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++){
    if (arr[n].src != ""){
        addHeadScript(arr[n].src);
    }
    else {
        // Evaluate the script `innerHTML`   OR
        // Create a script tag in the head and set it's content equal to arr[n].innerHTML
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one thing you could do:

```
var html = "Some html with a script <script>alert('test');</script>";

var frag = parsePartialHtml(html);

fixScriptsSoTheyAreExecuted(frag);


document.body.appendChild(frag);


function fixScriptsSoTheyAreExecuted(el) {
  var scripts = el.querySelectorAll('script'),
      script, fixedScript, i, len;

  for (i = 0, len = scripts.length; i < len; i++) {
    script = scripts[i];

    fixedScript = document.createElement('script');
    fixedScript.type = script.type;
    if (script.innerHTML) fixedScript.innerHTML = script.innerHTML;
    else fixedScript.src = script.src;
    fixedScript.async = false;

    script.parentNode.replaceChild(fixedScript, script);
  }
}


function parsePartialHtml(html) {
  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html'),
      frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
      childNodes = doc.body.childNodes;

  while (childNodes.length) frag.appendChild(childNodes[0]);

  return frag;
}
```